# How can I check if a Python variable is an integer, including numpy.int*?

Tags: python, integer

I would like to use an abstract way of checking whether a variable is an integer. I know I can do:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> isinstance(a, int)

True
```

However, this does not work for some special types of integers, e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.int64(1)
>>> isinstance(b, int)

False
```

I know I can also do:

```
>>> isinstance(b, np.integer)

True
```

But unfortunately, `np.integer` is not "abstract" enough to match an ordinary `int`:

```
>>> isinstance(a, np.integer)

False
```

What can I do to check and conclude that both `a` and `b` are "integers", preferably in a way that also matches other "integer-in-spirit" special data types that other packages than NumPy might bring to the party?

Comment: *isinstance(x, (np.integer, int))* Is that what you're looking for?